# I am getting model state error for property I did not set rule for using fluent validation

Tags: .net-core, fluentvalidation, modelstate

I want to perform a patch request, for model state not valid, I got validation errors for the property I set rule for and Id property I did not set rule.

NB: I have set SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter to be true in startUp.cs class.

This my validation rules for my model.

```
 public class UserForUpdateDtoValidator : AbstractValidator<UserForUpdateDTO>
{
    public UserForUpdateDtoValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Phone)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Enter a valid value")
            .Matches(@"^([0-9]{11})$").WithMessage("Enter a valid value");
        RuleFor(x => x.Gender)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Enter a valid value")
            .Must((u, s) => s.ToLower() =="male" || s.ToLower() == "female")
            .WithMessage("Enter a valid value");
    }
}
```

My action looks like this

```
[HttpPatch]
    [Route("{id}")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(SucessResponse<UserDTO>), 200)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateUser(UserForUpdateDTO model, Guid id)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(new ErrorResponse<Dictionary<string, string[]>>
                {
                    success = false,
                    message = "User details update failed",
                    errors  = ModelState.Error()
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my error message

```
{
  "success": false,
  "message": "User details update failed",
  "errors": {
     "id": [],
     "phone": [
        "Enter a valid value"
     ],
    "gender": [
        "Enter a valid value"
     ]
   }
}
```

Is there a way to exclude the id field from the error since I did not set the rule for it.

NB. If gender and phone property are valid, a 200 OK response is returned.

Comment: You're not getting any errors for id, just a model state key for the property. Could very well be default behaviour regardless of FV usage, I haven't checked. Couldn't you just perform a LINQ query to filter out model state kv pairs where the value is an empty array?

Comment: @rgvlee I added  `ModelState.Remove("Id")` to remove the id.